# Location based styling in WPF possible?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, resources, styling

In CSS it is possible to style HTML elements based on their location in the element tree:

```
div#container div#menu a
```

I'd like to do the same in WPF, so that only links in a menu section are styled.

- **Question #1:** One way or the other, is the above also possible in WPF?

I was thinking about the following for Separators nested in a StatusBar:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StatusBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,20,0" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This piece of XAML is included in a resource dictionary. The StatusBar shows up with a transparent background and correct padding. However, the green separator unfortunately  doesn't display. It just shows the default gray 1px wide bar.

- **Question #2:** If this is the correct solution, anyone knows why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can tell you that the Style's Resources are not translated to the type that the style is defined against, these resources are scoped to the style instance itself.

Comment: Yeah I imagine what we're looking for here is a "Setter" for the style whose property is the "Resources" property of the element the style is applied to. Somehow I don't think <Setter Property="Resources">...</Setter> would work though. This probably requires a code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon an answer myself. The code I mentioned is correct for every case, except the Separator. The Separator element should be styled with a specific key, detailed described here: http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/06/19/styling-separators-in-wpf.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post a while back where I took a CSS selector engine (Fizzler) and applied it to WPF:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/03/using-css-selectors-for-styling-in-wpf/

It allows you to use CSS selectors to target elements and apply styles to them. It also merges styles so that if multiple CSS selectors match, the styles from each are merged together.

See the following example:

```
<css:StyleSheet x:Key="cssStyles">
    <css:StyleSheet.Rules>

        <css:StyleRule Selector=".form Grid *" SelectorType="LogicalTree">
            <css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
                <css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Margin" Value="4,4,4,4"/>
                </css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
            </css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
        </css:StyleRule>

        <css:StyleRule Selector=".form TextBlock.mandatory">
            <css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
                <css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
            </css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
        </css:StyleRule>

        <css:StyleRule Selector="Border.form">
            <css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
                <css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
                </css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
            </css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
        </css:StyleRule>

        <css:StyleRule Selector=".form .title">
            <css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
                <css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="Padding" Value="3,3,3,3"/>
                    <css:StyleDeclaration Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                </css:StyleDeclarationBlock>
            </css:StyleRule.DeclarationBlock>
        </css:StyleRule>

    </css:StyleSheet.Rules>
</css:StyleSheet>
```